# What is the padding type for Elliptic Curve Crypto

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, elliptic-curve

After `SecKeyGeneratePair` for ECC, I try to encrypt plaintext by the public key. `SecKeyEncrypt` returns -4(errSecUnimplemented). I am not sure about the padding type is correct. I tried all the types in my xcode, they don't work as well. Can somebody explain why `SecKeyEncrypt` returns -4?

```
(NSData *)encrypt:(NSString *)plainTextString key:(SecKeyRef)publicKey {

    NSData *data = [plainTextString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    size_t encryptedDataLength = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);

    NSMutableData *encryptedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]
                                    initWithLength:encryptedDataLength];

    OSStatus err = SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey,
                                 kSecPaddingOAEP,
                                 [data bytes],
                                 [data length],
                                 [encryptedData mutableBytes],
                                 &encryptedDataLength);
    NSLog(@"errEXX:  %ld", err);

    [encryptedData setLength:encryptedDataLength];


    return encryptedData;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple's implementation only supports ECDSA, which can be used for signing but not encryption. For information about encrypting using elliptic curves using other schemes see [Is it possible to use elliptic curve cryptography for encrypting data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098005/is-it-possible-to-use-elliptic-curve-cryptography-for-encrypting-data?rq=1)

Comment: This is no longer true.   See: kSecKeyAlgorithmECIESEncryptionCofactorVariableIVX963SHA512AESGCM