# how to perform xor operation with ECC point and hash value

Tags: java, bouncycastle, xor, elliptic-curve

I need to perform XOR operation with ECC point and hashresult. that is

N=A xor hash; A-ECC Point. hash result is BigInteger. please let me know.

note: I am using bouncy castle API for implementing ECC in java. So can anybody please help me how to carry out xor operation with ECC point. and also tell me is BigInteger can be converted into ECFieldElement Object?.if so how? please let me know..

Thanks in advance!!!...

Comment: XOR between a "hash result" and an "ECC point" doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you can clarify the application. Perhaps you are looking for [ECIES](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3098005/238704)?

Comment: I am Implementing a user Authentication protocol using ECC.where I have computation with xor operation. first i will compute an ECC point then i need to perform xor operation with that point and hash result.that is N=A xor H(id); A-ECC point H-Hash Function id-user id.

Comment: Instead of clarifying you simply repeated what was in your question.